# How to force release a str in python?

Tags: python

Before the question I want to say sorry to you, because i'm not a native english and my english is very very poor.

i'm writing a python program to read a file to a string, 
and then analyze it, 
and then pass it to some other programs.(They can't work with stream)

simple code like this:

```
content = open("file").read()
if passItToA(content):
    A.portal(content)
del content
```

The problem is the string I read will not be release. Usually it lives until the end of process.

I know it is a feature of dynamic languages.
But it cause a lot of memory waste when i running 1000 duplicates processes in the same time.

Can I release it on my call?

Comment: Perhaps opening files and not closing them afterwards is what's causing your performance problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python relies heavily on the garbage collection.  To mark a value as being garbage (and let the collector do its work on it), just overwrite it:

```
content = ''
```

You also can delete the whole variable from the dictionary of variables:

```
del content
```

But concerning the string value, both work the same.

Just make sure that *no other* variable is still  holding a pointer to that string.  In your case, `A.portal()` and `passItToA()` should not create long-living pointers to the same string in order to be able to free it.

Comment: And I'm sorry abuout my poor english. Reference counting is not the problem.  The problem is about force dealloc memory space of a uesless long str.

Comment: I edit my questions to avoid this misunderstanding. Thank you again!

Comment: Actually, if you remove all references, the memory does get freed at once (there's a reference counting involved to achieve this). But Python internally has its own memory management system which allocates memory from the OS in larger chunks, and the freeing takes place within those chunks. This means that the memory once allocated from the OS will not get freed as soon as internally a string is freed again. Maybe calling `gc.collect()` has an influence on this (but I'm no GC guru, so I just take a guess).